# Fetch multiple nested maps in loop in firestore Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database that look like this:
[image]

How to fetch these xpS in the loop so that I don't have to explicitly write xp1, xp2, etc in the below code.
All these xp are maps.
This is my code:

```
{Experience && Experience.map((Experience) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="text-white">
                      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Experience.xp1.desc }} />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
```

```
const fetchExperience = async () => {
    await firebase
      .collection("portfolioV2")
      .doc("exp")
      .get()
      .then((docs) => {
        const data = docs.data();
        console.log(data);
        setExperience([...Experience, data]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exp` is a Firebase `document` and they can be presented in `JS` as simple `json` objects. To loop over those `EX`s wothout knowing them is just loopint trough an json without knowing it's keys:

```js
const fetchExperience = async () => {
  await firebase
    .collection("portfolioV2")
    .doc("exp")
    .get()
    .then((docs) => {
      const data = docs.data();

      //Here we loop trough the exp keys
      Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
        console.log("key", key);
        console.log("key data", data[key]);
      });

      console.log(data);
      setExperience([...Experience, data]);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });
};
```

Comment: its not from me, someone even downvoted the question also. :|
one more doubt, now I'm facing this issue with this code in react
`<div>this displays in page.
   {Experience && Experience.map((exp) => {
      Object.keys(exp).forEach((key) => {
                    return (<div className="text-white">
                        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: exp[key].desc,  //neither this 
}}
                        />
                        this doesn't displays in page.
                      </div>);
                  });
                })}
            </div>`

Comment: Can you pls write a separate question for your next error. You can share a link to it here. thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124373/render-nested-object-in-reactjs