# Render nested object in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase

I' have react js project that does the nested rendering. I'm seeing the output on consoles, but no on the web.

```
<div>
              {Experience &&
                Experience.map((exp) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="text-white">
                      {
                        //Here we loop trough the exp keys
                        Object.keys(exp).forEach((key) => {
                          // console.log("key", key);
                          // console.log("key data", exp[key]);
                          // console.log(exp[key].desc);
                          return (
                            <p
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: exp[key].desc,   //this doesnt display
                              }}
                            />
                          );
                        })
                      }
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you pls make a screenshot of the logs

Comment: What is the value of `Experience`? If this value comes from Firebase, show the code for how you read it and pass it to the rendering, and the data that you're reading from the database.

Comment: I got it working with `Object.keys(exp).map` instead of foreach. If this is the data structure of `Experience`. `const Experience = [
    { abc: { desc: '<p>abc</p>' }, efg: { desc: '<p>efg</p>' } },
    { hij: { desc: '<p>hij</p>' }, klm: { desc: '<p>klm</p>' } }
  ];`

Comment: Great to hear it worked out :)

Comment: Also make sure `className="text-white"` is not hiding the data because your text is white and background is also white. I hope it's not !! but happened to me as I have bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is more of knowing the diffrence between `foreach` and `map`.

That means `foreach` is not retuning anything and mutating data. If you change your `foreach` to `map`, things will work.

> map() allocates memory and stores return values. forEach() throws away
> return values and always returns undefined.
>
> forEach() will allow a callback function to mutate the current array.
> map() will instead return a new array.

**Note:** Make sure `className="text-white"` is not hiding your white text.